# Misaligned fixed-width font in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, kde-plasma

This is a weird one. I've been using Eclipse on Linux for years, with Inconolata as my fixed-width font of choice. I've recently switched to giving Kubuntu 11.10 a try, and at the same time upgraded to Eclipse Indigo. The problem I'm now having is that the fixed-width characters don't align vertically in the editor pane. Here's an image to illustrate (there are no tabs in this sample, not that that should matter anyway):

[image: screen grab from Eclipse editor window]

This is a screen grab, scaled 2x in the Gimp. I've added some guide lines to highlight the issue.

In all the time I've been using Eclipse on Linux, I've *never* had anything like this. I don't know whether it's a KDE problem, an Eclipse problem, or some other weird thing. dpkg reports that this is version 001.010-2 of `ttf-inconolata`.

Any suggestions for debugging for fixing this would be very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some digging, I found the answer. In my `~/.fonts.config`, I set the autohint property because otherwise some of the fonts, e.g. in Firefox or pidgin are rendered too small or too thin. However, autohinting screws up fixed-width character alignment in Eclipse - I don't know why, and would welcome an explanation.

The fix was to turn off autohinting for just Inconsolata. So in `.fonts.config`, I have:

```
<match target="font">
 <test name="family" compare="eq" qual="any"><string>Inconsolata</string></test>
 <edit name="autohint" mode="assign"><bool>false</bool></edit> 
 <edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign"><const>hintnone</const></edit> 
</match>
```

and all is well.